# Unable to locate package ros-indigo-openni-kinect

Tags: raspberry-pi, kinect, openni, ros

I am working on raspberry pi B. OS is rasbian and ı have installed ros indigo using [this tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi) on raspberry pi. Now ı want to work with raspberry pi + kinect. When ı run

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

ı had an error like this

```
[openni.launch] is neither a launch file in package [openni_launch] nor is [openni_launch] a launch file name The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Then ı try to install openni but ı had an error is below.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni-kinect
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-openni-kinect
```

How can ı run kinect on raspberry pi. pls help??

Answer (score 1):

You could have had a look at [ROS Answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/197957/i-cant-install-open-ni-on-indigo-what-linux-version-should-i-install-instead/) before asking.

Anyway, as it is explained there, `openni-kinect` is deprecated and it is suggested to use [`openni-launch`](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch) instead.

To install this package:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni-launch
```

Comment: I tried it but have same error " Unable to locate package"                                                          pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-openni-launch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-openni-launch

Comment: It doesn't seem to be able to locate the `ros-indigo-openni-launch` package. Have you tried with this: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`? If so and nothing changed, paste here the result of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know to get the kinect working on the Raspberry pi? You can retrieve the depth map and the rgb matrix with this library, basically all you need.
Check this out:
https://github.com/xxorde/librekinect

Maybe StackEchange is a friendly zone but in this case ROS answer is the most suited place to ask.